# Windows 10 Memory Leak not visible in processes

Tags: windows-10, memory, memory-leaks

I am currently struggling to interpret the data regarding my memory usage and my system appears to be leaking memory which is not visible within any process.

Process RAM Usage (Size):

[image]

Process RAM Usage (Percent):

[image]

RAM Usage (Resource Monitor):

[image]

As per my Resource Monitor, I have 12000+ MB of memory "in use" which is nowhere near what I see on my task manager view. Resource Monitor shows the largest contributor to Committedng.exe taking up around 1GB of Committed memory (This is not shown in Task Manager).

I have been looking around for solutions and noticed a few common useful pieces of information can be provided such as a poolmon.exe output sorted by paged data and number of bytes as can be found here.

[image]

[image]

Any suggestions on what could be causing this or any suggestions towards further diagnosing the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In Task Manager, from the Performance tab, click on Memory on the left.  How much Pool memory is being used, please share both paged and non-paged?  If you restart the computer, maybe leave it a couple of minutes what are these values then?  This might help understand if you have a pool leak.

Comment: @HelpingHand 642MB Paged, 632MB Non Paged. Nothing too significant it seems. I haven't restarted as I am currently unable to reproduce this leak however it occurs every few days.

Comment: `RAMMap` is an extremely helpful tool, unlike Task Manager.  You really should use the image upload function instead of using non-imgur image sites.

Comment: Yeah, nothing too alarming then. From the poolmon screenshot, I think the highest diff is the "Process objects" tag PROC and this is only 256MB if that's bytes.

Comment: You say "problem"... but is there any issue, aside, from apparently high RAM usage? Do any processes suffer due to this statistic?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I am seeing freezes occasionally where I cannot move the mouse which I currently believe comes down to this root issue.

Comment: I have never seen a memory issue caused an I/O issue as you described.  I have seen an HDD that is about to fail, cause that exact problem.

Comment: @Ramhound, RAMMap output can be found here https://i.imgur.com/zoeTwBa.png. How would you suggest I check the state of my HDD?

Comment: @Qinusty - Any application that will report the S.M.A.R.T data for the drive will be helpful.

Comment: @Ramhound HDD seems good https://i.imgur.com/hrZkLL6.png

Comment: I would do some research on how your drive reports "Seek Error Rate", which indicates an issue with the mechanical subsystem.

Comment: @Qinusty has this problem persisted?  Did it happen to go away after rebooting?  I found [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1338367) and yours after having the same problem - 98% RAM usage but only 1-2GB total (of 16GB) actually appearing in Task Manager.  [This answer about "Zombie Handles"](https://superuser.com/a/1338765) showed me over 300 zombie processes.  Not sure what caused them, but after rebooting I haven't had any immediate problem.